# AWS Instance disk reads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1.i have created a load balancer with two instances say E1 & E2,

2.when i see the disk reads about these two instances in cloud watch or in ec2 monitoring tools.

3.i observed E2 instance getting more disk reads.

4.But both the instances have same code and same configurations (m3.medium).

Can you please suggest me how track these disk reads and make it same for both instances.

Answer (score 0):

- You can looks for utilization of other resources (network, cpu) on
  both of these instances.
- You can check "top" to see which processes are running on both
  instances & compare if its as expected.
- Check /var/log/syslog to seeif there are any error or issue.
  (last 2 assume these are some Linux installs)

Alternatively, if possible, you can just terminate E2 & setup a new instance and see if the pattern is still same.